# can not make text view align to right in scroll view

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have a text view and I use it to show Arabic in the text view. therfore, I want to align textview in scrollview to right.
I tried several properties to make it as I expect but didnt work for me.

Here is the xml file

```
<LinearLayout

  android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="25dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >
    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If anyone can help me to correct this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just 1 change and you are done

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_below="@id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview" >

    <!-- In LinearLayout attributes,
    Replace: android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    With:    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginBottom="23dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/padding_maintextview"
            android:text="@string/text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```